# jQuery click event does not fire function the way it should

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, chat

There is a great chat example on css-tricks that I think is great for beginners in PHP. (https://css-tricks.com/jquery-php-chat/) As I'm looking at it, I notice there is no send button. This is pretty important for a good UI. So I'm thinking, "This can't be too hard right?" and I wrote JQuery to make a send button. I'm not getting any errors in the console, but it is not sending. You can look over my live demo at the bottom. But I can't get that send button to work. Pressing enter sends the data, so why shouldn't pressing a button? There might be a completely different approach than what I'm trying. For example faking a keystroke when the button is pressed. But I have tried that too and it doesn't work right. By default, the chat is constantly waiting for an enter keystroke. It does this with the code below.

```
$('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {                             
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    //send message
});
```

And that's great, but I need a button to send the message. So I modified the code to say:

```
$('#sendbutton').click(function(e) {                             
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    //send message
});
```

Should work right? Nope. So I try again, with a different approach. But time after time, the jQuery hits me in the back. Over and over again. After doing my research, I think the problem may be that this snippet is inside of another function that looks like this:

```
$(function() {
 //more code stuffs
  $('#sendie').keyup(function(e) {                           
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
    //send message
  });
});
```

So, somehow, it cant find my button. And I think that it is due to the containing function thing. Maybe it's another problem though. The entire function consists of:

```
// watch textarea for release of key press
             $('#sendie').keyup(function myFunction(e) {    

                  if (e.keyCode == 13) { 

                    var text = $(this).val();
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 

                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                        chat.send(text, name);
                        console.log('message was sent by hitting enter. Message: ' + text + "Length: " + length + "."); 
                        $(this).val("");
                    } else {
                        $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));

                    }   
                  }
             });
```

Here is a demo of what I am trying (without the php):

```js
// ask user for name with popup prompt    
        // it's annoyting for the demo so I got rid of it
        //var name = prompt("Enter your chat name:", "GuestCow");
        
        // default name is 'Guest-Cow'
     if (!name || name === ' ') {
        name = "GuestCow"; 
     }
     
     // strip tags
     name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
     
     // display name on page
     $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");
        console.log("username is " + name);

        function newName() {
            // ask user for name with popup prompt    
        var name = prompt("Enter your new chat name:", "GuestCow");
        
        // default name is 'Guest-Cow'
        if (!name || name === ' ') {
           name = "GuestCow";   
        }
        
        // strip tags
        name = name.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        
        // display name on page
        $("#name-area").html("You are: <span>" + name + "</span>");
        console.log("username was changed to " + name);
        }
     
     // kick off chat
        var chat =  new Chat();
     $(function() {
     
       chat.getState(); 
       
       // watch textarea for key presses
             $("#sendie").keydown(function(event) {  
             
                 var key = event.which;  
           
                 //all keys including return.  
                 if (key >= 33) {
                   
                     var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                     var length = this.value.length; 
                     console.log("key was pressed");
                     
                     // don't allow new content if length is maxed out
                     if (length >= maxLength) {  
                         event.preventDefault();  
                     }  
                  }  
                                                       });
       // watch textarea for release of key press
       $('#sendie').keyup(function myFunction(e) { 
             
         if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
         
                    var text = $(this).val();
        var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 
                     
                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                     
               chat.send(text, name);
                        console.log('message was sent by hitting enter. Message: ' + text + "Length: " + length + "."); 
               $(this).val("");
               
                    } else {
                    
         $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
         
        } 
        
        
         }
             });

             // watch button for click
             /*$('#sendbutton').click(function(e) {   
                                 
                  
                    var text = $(this).val();
                    var maxLength = $(this).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 
                     
                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 
                     
                        chat.send(text, name);
                        console.log('messgae was sent by pressing button');  
                        $(this).val("");
                        
                    } else {
                    
                        $(this).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                           
                  }
             });*/

          });
          
          function doOnBlur() {
        document.getElementById("sendie").style.borderBottom = "2px solid rgb(169, 169, 169)";
        document.getElementById('progressinner').style.width = "0px";
    }

    function doOnFocus() {
        document.getElementById("sendie").style.borderBottom = "none";
        document.getElementById('progressinner').style.width = "360px";
    }
    
    //ajax
    /* 
Created by: Kenrick Beckett

Name: Chat Engine
*/

var instanse = false;
var state;
var mes;
var file;

function Chat () {
    this.update = updateChat;
    this.send = sendChat;
 this.getState = getStateOfChat;
}

//gets the state of the chat
function getStateOfChat(){
 if(!instanse){
   instanse = true;
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: {  
         'function': 'getState',
      'file': file
      },
      dataType: "json",
   
      success: function(data){
       state = data.state;
       instanse = false;
      },
   });
 }  
}

//Updates the chat
function updateChat(){
  if(!instanse){
   instanse = true;
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: {  
         'function': 'update',
      'state': state,
      'file': file
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
       if(data.text){
      for (var i = 0; i < data.text.length; i++) {
                            $('#chat-area').append($("<p>"+ data.text[i] +"</p>"));
                            document.title = "Chat - 1 new message";
                        }          
       }
       document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;
       instanse = false;
       state = data.state;
      },
   });
  }
  else {
   setTimeout(updateChat, 1500);
  }
}

//send the message
function sendChat(message, nickname)
{       
    updateChat();
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "process.php",
     data: {  
        'function': 'send',
     'message': message,
     'nickname': nickname,
     'file': file
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
      updateChat();
     },
  });
}
```

```css
*                               { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0px !important; }
body                            { font: 12px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif; background: #333; }
#page-wrap                      { width: 500px; margin: 5px auto; position: relative; border-radius: 10px; }

.darkMode                       { width: 500px; margin: 5px auto; position: relative; }

#chat-wrap                      { margin: 0 0 15px 0; }
#chat-area                      { height: 300px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-wrap: break-word; border: 1px solid #666; border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px; background: white; }
#chat-area span                 { color: white; background: #333; padding: 4px 8px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
#chat-area p                    { padding: 8px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; line-height: 1.5;}

/*#name-area                      { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 0; color: white; font: bold 12px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif; text-align: right; }   
#name-area span                 { color: #fa9f00; }*/
#modbox       { background-color: red !important; color: white; background: #333; padding: 4px 8px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; margin: 0 5px 0 0; }

#send-message-area p            { float: left; color: white; font-size: 14px; }
#sendie                         { z-index: 1000000; outline: 0 !important; resize: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;color: white; background-color: #333; width: 360px; padding: 5px; font: 13px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(169, 169, 169); float: right; }

/*New Css----Turns out it's broken... :(  */
#chat-area::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 1em;
        }
        
#chat-area::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            border-left: 2px solid #3a3a3a;
        }
        
#chat-area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #333;
            outline: 1px solid slategrey;
        }
        
#chat-area::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background-color: #3a3a3a;
        }

        /* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 17px;
  float: left;
  top: 0px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(13px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(13px);
  transform: translateX(13px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#menu { display: none; }

.sendbuttoncontainer {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.textareacontain {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.progressinner {
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  /*nice google blue color*/
  background-color: #4885ed;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 44px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
       -o-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
          transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

/*#sendie:focus + .progressinner {
  width: 100%;
}*/

#sendbutton {
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 5px;
  outline: 0px !important;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
       -o-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
          transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#sendbutton:active {
  outline: 0px !important;
}

#sendbutton:hover {
  background-color: #f22a02;
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="setInterval('chat.update()', 1000)" onclick="document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';">


<div class="darkMode" style="
 -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;">
   <label class="switch">
  <input class="checker" onclick="javascript: (
function () { 
    var css = 'html {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);' +
        '-moz-filter: invert(100%);' + 
        '-o-filter: invert(100%);' + 
        '-ms-filter: invert(100%); }' +
        '#modbox {background-color: #00FFFF;}',
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');

if (!window.counter) { window.counter = 1;} else  { window.counter ++;
    console.log('darkmode activated');
if (window.counter % 2 == 0) { var css ='html {-webkit-filter: invert(0%); -moz-filter: invert(0%); -o-filter: invert(0%); -ms-filter: invert(0%); } #modbox {background-color: red;}'}
 };

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
 }());
" type="checkbox" title="Dark Mode">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<p style="
            float: left; color: white;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;" id="noInvertTwo">&nbsp;&nbsp;Dark Mode On/Off</p><p style="float: right;"><a href="javascript:newName();" style="color: lightgrey;">Change Username</a> <a href="javascript:window.close();" style="color: lightgrey;">Close Chat</a></p>
</div>
<br style="
 -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;">

    <div id="page-wrap">
    
        
        


        
        <div id="chat-wrap"><div id="chat-area" class="chat-area">
            <p style=""><span2 id="modbox">Chat-Mod</span2>Basically, pressing the send button, while it's supposed to send somthing, is doing nothing. Please note that this demo does not work because it does not have the php nessacarry for it to.</p>
            <p style=""><span>Details</span>Ignore the DOM styleing errors in the console. Mainly, I think that my problem is with some global variables not really being so global after all. I'm having a hard time identifying this error. But I will even accept another solution to submit the content to that chat that uses a button press.</p><!--<p id="name-area"></p>-->
        </div></div>
        
        <form id="send-message-area">
            <p id="noInvert">Your message: </p><!--<br><button onclick="sendText()">send</button>-->
            <div class="textareacontain">
                <textarea tabindex="2" id="sendie" onfocus="doOnFocus()" onblur="doOnBlur()" maxlength="200" placeholder="Say Something... (Press Enter to Send)"></textarea>
                <div class="progressinner" id="progressinner"></div>
            </div><br>
            </form>
            <div class="sendbuttoncontainer">
                <button id="sendbutton" onclick="sendthetext();">Send&#9721;</button>
            </div>
        
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Anyway, sorry for the long explanation. And I'm sure I'm just missing somthing super easy for anyone else. So If I could have another set of eyes look over my code I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The keycode check is only relevant to a keyboard event, which was captured by the #sendie textarea. A button click carries no keyboard keycode at all.

Just remove the if-keycode condition and things would probably be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have formed an answer on yours below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476874/11837127

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Koala Yeung, I have formed an answer. Koala said that because the click event does not carry a keycode, my function was not running. So I removed the line `if (e.keyCode == 13{}` however, it was still not running the function. So I did some research on bug checking. And one good way I found is to place `console.log('');` in places where a function or an if/else statement might be ran. My original function then looked like this:

```
// watch button for click
             $('#sendbutton').click(function(e) {  

                    console.log("it got this far at least");

                    var text = $(self).val();
                    var maxLength = $(self).attr("maxlength");  
                    var length = text.length; 

                    // send 
                    if (length <= maxLength + 1) { 

                        console.log("passed maxlenght test");

                        chat.send(text, name);
                        console.log('message was sent by Pressing Send. Message: ' + text + " Length: " + length + "."); 
                        //clears the textarea after send
                        $(self).val("");

                    } else {
                        console.log('did not pass maxlength test')
                        $(self).val(text.substring(0, maxLength));
                    }   

             });
```

Then if I got `it got this far at least` then I would know it received the button press. After that, I got the string `did not pass maxlength test` which means it ran the else after the if statement, even though I wanted it to run the if statement itself. That's about when I realized that it was trying to check the maxlegth of the self property. But a button doesn't have a maxlength attribute! So I replaced all of the self properties with `'#sendie'` and It worked! It actually worked. And that is rare for my javascript 'skill'. And that is also good for bug checking. I learned something today. And I am so gratefull for it too.